# SQL query - How to add same ID values to values from another column?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have two columns:

```
ID   name 
--------------
NULL Bose 
NULL Bose 
NULL Computer 
NULL Bose 
NULL Monitor 
NULL Monitor 
NULL Computer 
NULL Bose 
NULL Phone 
NULL Computer
```

Need to add unique values like this:
Values should start from some number like 400.

```
ID name 
------------
400 Bose 
400 Bose 
401 Computer 
400 Bose 
402 Monitor 
402 Monitor 
401 Computer 
400 Bose 
403 Phone 
401 Computer
```

I have tried with DISTINCT but cant figure it out, can somebody please help? Thank you!

Comment: If multiple rows have the same ID they're not unique, you also shouldn't really have any need to have multiple rows with the same ID and name. This just seems like your database is designed incredibly badly.

Comment: Sorry, by unique i mean that for every name have its own ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  your_table s
JOIN
(SELECT (@r:=@r+1) rn, t.name FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM your_table) t
,(SELECT @r:=399) nums) tab
ON tab.name = s.name
SET s.ID = tab.rn;
```

Here is working code at SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b831ed/1

Comment: I updated the query like this:
UPDATE your_table s
JOIN
(SELECT (@r:=@r+1) rn, t.name, t1.name1 FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM your_table) t
,(SELECT DISTINCT name1 FROM your_table) t1
,(SELECT @r:=399) nums) tab
ON tab.name = s.name and tab.name1 = s.name1
SET s.ID = tab.rn;
because "name1" column is related to column "name" and some duplicates must get different "id" on column "name".
The problem is that the query tooks 40 minutes to complete and IDs are given like this: 400, 404, 409, 414 etc. Is there a way to optimize this query? I have 4000-9000 rows.

Comment: Do you want to assign a unique ID for a `(name, name1)` combination?

Comment: ID name1 name 
------------
400 sub1 Bose 
400 sub5 Bose 
401 sub2 Computer 
400 sub1 Bose 
402 sub3 Monitor 
402 sub3 Monitor 
401 sub2 omputer 
400 sub1 Bose 
403 sub4 Phone 
401 sub2 Computer. sub5 Bose must get new Id because name1 is different, my updated query does that, but extremly slow. You can check here: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e360/1)

Comment: Thanks for providing SQL Fiddle link. It made it easier. Here is the link of modified query http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e089d7/1. I just added one more field in `SELECT DICTINCT` statement. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in various ways.  One method is to use variables.

```
update table t cross join
       (select @name := '',@prevname := '',  @id := 399) const
    set id = (case when (@prevname := @name) is null then null
                   when (@name := name) is null then null
                   when @prevname = name then @id
                   else @id := @id + 1
              end)
    order by name;
```

The use of the `case` statement is simply to allow variable assignments in the `update` clause.

Comment: Thank You for fast response! But this added half of ID values to 399 and another half to 400, (i have ~4000 rows) same IDs to different names.

Comment: @androza . . . I left out that all important update of the `id` in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think First you have to make the master table for above:
and then update the foregin keys (IDs) against the names for the respectve PK-FK relationship.